# InterlockedExchange (or similar atomic operation) within a Critical Section?

Tags: c++, synchronization, critical-section

I have seen some repeated code (methods to be precise) where they are entering the critical section and then using InterlockedExchange...Does this make sense since I thought that this operation was infact atomic and would not require such synchronization?

```
{ 
  EnterCricSectionLock lock (somelock);
  InterlockedExchange(&somelong, static_cast<long>(newlongVal));
}
```

That is basically what there is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal exchange is generally not atomic. It is however ok to do it while owning a mutex, if all other uses is protected by the same mutex. It is also ok to use an atomic exchange, if all other uses are atomic. The only logical reason I can think of to do an atomic exchange while owning the mutex, is that not all uses of this value is mutex protected.

Comment: Is "not" atomic? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx): "Sets a 32-bit variable to the specified value as an atomic operation." Of course, what you say about "all other users" is required: all of them must use an interlocked function as well.

Comment: An atomic exchange IS atomic, of course. What I meant was that a normal exchange is generally not atomic.

Comment: OK, sorry for misunderstanding (but since the question was in particular about `InterlockedExchange` I don't feel to bad about it ;-)

Comment: It was a bit unclear (too early in the morning). I have edited and hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

A single atomic operation won't need a CS, but it can act as a fence to make anything altered while the lock is held globally visible (IIRC, explicit fences are for SSE2+, but interlocked ops don't need SSE at all), however then it would need to be *after* any global stores.

Where this might make sense is that the CS is used to lock access to something else, and thus global being exchanged on is not part of the lock.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx) it "generates a full memory barrier (fence)". So I guess that is not requirement to use a CS in addition to the interlocked op. +1 for the note about it probably being part of a "bigger" invariant to protect with the CS.

Comment: @Christian.K: my wording was a little poor, made it a little clearer.